# Get div height depand on parent div height and parent height depand on document height

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my sample code

```
<div id="one">
height based on screen 

     <div id="two">
      height based on id="one"
       <div>
          height based on id="two"
       </div> 
     </div>"

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body { height:100%; }
#one { height:some%; }
#two { height:some%; }
```

CSS - no JS needed here (unless you want to change the heights later).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$(this).parent().height();` for every `div`

Comment: Where should this be called?

Answer (score 0):

Set Height and width in %. It will take the parent div's Height and Width.